# How to add java source code for AspectJ in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, aop, aspectj, javadoc

I am learning AOP with Spring framework and I want to set the javadoc for AOP in eclipse. So what I did I downloaded `aspectj-1.8.10.jar` from eclipse web site https://eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php#install then I installed that jar and got 4 new jar files: `aspectjrt.jar`, `aspectjtools.jar`, `aspectjweaver.jar`, `org.aspectj.matcher.jar` which I added to my class path in eclipse. Now what I want is to add source files for these jars so, for example, when I hover over @Aspect I want to be able to see what this annotation represents. Unfortunately I can not find the source files for these jars, on the eclipse website mentioned above there is a file `aspectj-1.8.10-src.jar` but I'm not sure what to do with it, I tried to attach this file directly in the build path for each of the jars mentioned above but it didn't do the trick. Also I thought that maybe I had to install `aspectj-1.8.10-src.jar` the way I installed `aspectj-1.8.10.jar` so I would get 4 source files, but I'm not sure how (if possible) to install it, when I double click `aspectj-1.8.10-src.jar`, installation does not get triggered. 
So can you please help me out to add javadoc for `AspectJ 1.8.10` in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Select the library in your Eclipse project explorer window, click right button, select properties, select javasource attachment or javadoc location and enter the path to the source or javadoc file.

But I would suggest to use maven to maintain the dependencies of your project. It makes getting javadoc much easier, because libraries, source code and javadoc are fetch from a central repository. You just add the library you need in your project configuration (pom.xml file) and the other files are fetched for you.

Comment: I know how to attach the source code, but I don't know where to get it. I have 4 jars I need the source code for:`aspectjrt.jar`, `aspectjtools.jar`, `aspectjweaver.jar`, `org.aspectj.matcher.jar` and I have one source code file `aspectj-1.8.10-src.jar` from eclipse website mentioned in my question, I tried to to attach it to each of these jars but it didn't work (and I don't think you can attach the source code for the whole library only to one individual jar at the time). Speaking of maven thanks but I'm not using it now this is just a simple java project.

Comment: I prefer maven even for simple java projects, because if I add the dependencies maven will download the source code and the javadoc as well without any manually actions. I've had the same problems as you and I didn't wanted to solve these problems again and again.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need all those libraries. Please first learn which one serves which purpose. E.g. *aspectjrt* is the runtime. When using Spring AOP you actually do not really use AspectJ, only a subset of its syntax. Thus, the runtime is needed for identifying some of the annotation classes. However, *aspectjweaver* is only needed if you want to use full AspectJ in a load-time weaving (LTW) scenario, with or without Spring. The weaver lib is a superset of the runtime, so you only need one of them. Last, but not least, *aspectjtools* again is a superset of the weaver lib and contains the AspectJ compiler (among other tools). This is only needed for compile-time weaving as part of your toolchain.
2. I do not think that source code and Javadoc will help you much in learning AspectJ. I suggest you read the [Spring manual's AOP chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) describing both proxy-based Spring AOP and full AspectJ integration via LTW. If you want to learn AspectJ basics and maybe just use AspectJ without Spring (which is what I do), read the [AspectJ documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php).
3. If you are still not convinced and want to add source and JavaDoc to your Eclipse project, why don't you follow *jaysee*'s advice and use Maven? Then you get all the source/javadoc libs for free. But anyway, you can also load those JARs directly from Maven Central, e.g. the [source and javadoc for AspectJ runtime 1.8.10](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.10/). Good luck! But I assume you will be disappointed because the AspectJ JavaDoc is really bad for learning purposes and not suited to understanding how to actually use AspectJ.